# how to get outlook additem

Tags: vba, outlook

additem doesn't work in outllok 2010 even the application is trigerred. my outlook product is not activated. Is this matter ?

```
Public Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim myForward As MailItem
    MsgBox "item"
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
```

Comment: How is myOlItems variable declared and initialized?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you declared the source object with the `WithEvents` keywords like the following sample code shows:

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items 

Public Sub Initialize_handler() 
 Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items 
End Sub 
 

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) 
 Dim myOlMItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myOlAtts As Outlook.Attachments 
 Set myOlMItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 myOlMItem.Save 
 Set myOlAtts = myOlMItem.Attachments 
 ' Add new contact to attachments in mail message 
 myOlAtts.Add Item, olByValue 
 myOlMItem.To = "Sales Team" 
 myOlMItem.Subject = "New contact" 
 myOlMItem.Send 
End Sub
```

Also it makes sense to make sure the source object (in your case `myOlItems`) is initialized correctly.

Finally, you need to make sure VBA is allowed to run the code, i.e. VBA macros are not blocked in Outlook.